# How to load static resources in Lightning Components from zip file

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I have created a folder name `myResources`. It has two sub folders `styles` and `scripts`. `scripts` folder has two files `js1.js` and `js2.js`. `styles` folder has one file `styles.css`.

myResources->scripts->js1.js
myResources->scripts->js2.js
myResources->styles->styles.css

And I am trying to load it as below

```
<ltng:require styles="/resource/myResources/styles/styles.css" 
                  scripts='/resource/myResources/scripts/js1.js,
                          /resource/myResources/scripts/js2.js' 
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.setup}" />
```

I have also tried

```
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.myResources+ '/styles/styles.css'}" />
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',', 
                           $Resource.myResources+ '/scripts/js1.js', 
                           $Resource.myResources+ '/scripts/js2.js')}" 
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.setup}" />
```

But not luck so far, I don't know what I am doing wrong.
My static resource name is `myResources`.
**Note: I have upload them individual files not .zip file It loads successfully.**
Following this tutorial [Loading External JavaScript And CSS Libraries To Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/05/loading-external-js-css-libraries-lightning-components.html)

Comment: Are you sure you named your static resource "resource" ?

Comment: yes I am sure it is `myResources` I can see in setup->static resource . It has name is `myResources` and type `application/octet-stream`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your folder name and static resource name both are `myResources`, its leading upto a confusion.

You need to include your folder name as well in the path like this.

```
<ltng:require styles="/resource/myResources/myResources/styles/styles.css" 
                  scripts='/resource/myResources/myResources/scripts/js1.js,
                          /resource/myResources/myResources/scripts/js2.js' 
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.setup}" />
```